# Alloy compiler failed

Tags: android, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

Hi I running my app on: 
Name = Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Version = 6.1.7601 
Architecture = 64bit # CPUs = 4 Memory = 4176924672

**Node.js** 
Node.js Version = 0.10.29 npm Version = 1.4.14

**Titanium CLI** 
CLI Version = 5.0.3

**Titanium SDK**
 SDK Version = 5.0.0.GA 
Target Platform = android

when i try to compile and run for the android device, i getting following Error:

Executing Alloy compile: cmd /s /c C:\Users\Dell.appcelerator\install\5.0.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\bin\alloy compile C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\Oboulo_android\app --config platform=android,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=test,target=device --no-colors 'C:\Users\Dell.appcelerator\install\5.0.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\bin\alloy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[ERROR] : Alloy compiler failed 
TRACE | titanium exited with exit code 1 [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
App was running properly with lover CLI version before taking update from 4.1.0 to 5.0.0 today morning.

Any body can help me out to debug this issue. (I tried even reinstalling Alloy from Command prompt by: npm install -g alloy but still no use...

Comment: I have the same problem. I suspect than this is because compiler calling alloy directly without 'node' in `cmd /s /c C:\Users\Dell.appcelerator\install\5.0.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\bin\alloy compile`. I think the correct is `cmd /s /c node C:\Users\Dell.appcelerator\install\5.0.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\bin\alloy compile`. I trying change the hooks/alloy.js than call this, but cannot view any changes. Any news I post here.

Answer (score 3):

This should work (simplier way):

Just run

```
appc alloy install plugin
```

in the project directory.

Source: https://community.appcelerator.com/topic/3388/executing-alloy-compile-error-after-update/10

Comment: Hi, i did as you said to install alloy in project directory, but still no positive result. Still facing same issue. I even tried as **gabrieloliveira** said, still no use.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I resolve this problem.

First I remove `%userprofile%\.appcelerator\install\5.0.1\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium` folder.

So installed appc-cli-titanium again with `npm install appc-cli-titanium`.

After this, the error continued, so, today I found one special folder in project folder, is `plugins/ti.alloy`. This folder contains a copy of `alloy/hooks/alloy.js` than make a call to alloy compiler.

So copy `%userprofile%\.appcelerator\install\5.0.1\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\hooks\alloy.js` to your project folder `plugins/ti.alloy/hooks/alloy.js`

Ps: Replace 5.0.1 by your version. Check in .appcelerator\install folder.

Now works!

Answer (score 1):

This is Working

npm install alloy -g

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium/issues/226